# Extracting data using arcpy.da.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, list

I have a shapefile of point features showing fire locations in a given year. One of the fields is named "YYYYMMDD" and indicates the corresponding date that that fire happened. In Python, I am trying to use the arcpy.da.SearchCursor function to append each date into a list and find the most recent fire by date.

My code looks like this:

```
listname = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fires, "YYYYMMDD")

for row in cursor:
    listname.append(row)

print 'the first fire date is ',min(listname),'.'
print 'the last fire date is ',max(listname),'.'
```

What prints for min and max listname is: (20010515.0,) and (20011002.0,)
But what I would like to get as an output is: 20010514 and 20011002

How do can I get that as my output?

I tried indexing what I got to exclude what I don't need but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to grab the first element of each row and convert to int.

```
listname = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fires, "YYYYMMDD")

for row in cursor:
    listname.append(int(row[0]))

print 'the first fire date is {0}.'.format(min(listname))
print 'the last fire date is {0}.'.format(max(listname))
```

Comment: You may also want to utilize a `sql_clause` in your search cursor something like  `sqlClause = (None, ‘ORDER BY ‘ + "YYYYMMDD" +  ‘ DESC’)` and then add that to your Search Cursor like this: `cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fires, "YYYYMMDD", sql_clause = sqlClause)`. That way your field will already be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

In your cursor loop - change to:

```
listname.append(row[0])
```

and for your printing - change to:

```
print "The first fire date is {0}".format(min(listname))
print "The last fire date is {0}".format(max(listname))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should note that, in your case, row is a list (even if there is only one field). so listname becomes a list of lists. you need to take the value out of your list.

```
listname = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fires, "YYYYMMDD")

for row in cursor:
    listname.append(row[0])
```

then you can format it as you want, e.g. :

```
print "the first date is " + str(min(listname))
```