# Select the most recent date from a table using Python/arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

Given a dataset with a date field, how would I select the row with the most recent date using Python or ArcPy?

Comment: Here are some approaches that were noted in another post.  Note the sections where the OP is wanting the most recent fire:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95378/how-to-extract-data-using-arcpy-da-searchcursor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building from evv_gis comment:

1. Use [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to iterate through layer and assign date values to list
2. Use max method on list to get the newest value
3. [Make feature laye](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000)r of layer
4. Use the [select layer by attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) method on feature layer with value from step 2

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of completeness here is my final script, minus making a feature layer, which I will add in production.

```
listdates = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layername, "Date_Mod")

for row in cursor:
    listdates.append(row)

maxdate = max(listdates)
maxdatestr = str(maxdate)
datestr = maxdatestr[19:31]

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layername, "NEW_SELECTION", "Date_Mod = date '" + datestr + " 00:00:00'")
```

Thanks to everyone that answered and commented.